# Error in compile Android project via terminal with gradle 4.6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

My project today was updated to Gradle 4.6, before I used the following line to compile the project via Android Studio terminal:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --configure-on-demand --daemon
```

Now an error occurs when I try to compile the project with that command. I have tried to read the documentation as shown in the output, but I can't find a topic about my particular problem.

Error log:

```
Task :app:compileTargetApi23DebugJavaWithJavac 

error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

I appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error produced by Java 10, I uninstalled the JDK 10 and the compiler works again!

Comment: This is very helpful for me. It solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Was banging my had to a wall until I found your answer :)